# dynamically create and assign variables to prometheus metrics in Python

Tags: python, prometheus

I'm trying to iterate through a **list** and get key and the corresponding values i need like `category`, `current_severity`, `event`, `component_name` and `component_type`.

The challenge i am facing is, the content of the list might change, like the **key** and **values** will remain the same but the stanzas might be less, zero or more. So i need something more dynamic.

I need to assign the dynamically created variables to prometheus metrics which will also need to be dynamic.

i tried to create dynamic variables like this, it partially works, like it creates duplicates.

the code i tried:-

```
url = htpp://url
data = json.loads(r.get(url, headers=headers, 
verify=False).content.decode('UTF-8'))

var = string.ascii_lowercase
d = {}
k = 0

for value in data:
      d[var[k]] = value['software']
      k += 1
      d[var[k]] = value['current_severity']
      k += 1
      print(d)
```

This prints out duplicates like

```
 {'a': 'software', 'b': low}
 {'a': 'software', 'b': low, 'c': 'software', 'd': medium}
```

I want to assign the values to variables and those to be assigned to prometheus metrics. Prometheus metrics are also to be created based on how many ever variables are there.

My desired output:

```
metric = Metric('prometheus_metric_name', 'prometheus metric name', 'gauge')
metric.add_sample('prometheus_metric_name', value=float(0), labels={'software':(variable of software will go here), 'severity':(variable of current_severity will go here)})
```

the `metric.add_sample` line should be created dynamically for how many ever stanzas have been returned. Below is the list returned by `data`

```
[{'category': 'software', 'code': 110, 'actual': '["5.1.4"]', 'opened': 
'2018-10-16T09:18:12Z', 'component_type': 'update', 'event': 'new update 
available', 'current_severity': 'info', 'details': '', 'expected': None, 
'id': 10088862, 'component_name': 'Purity//FA'}, {'category': 'software', 
'code': 67, 'actual': None, 'opened': '2018-10-18T01:14:45Z', 
'component_type': 'host', 'event': 'misconfiguration', 'current_severity': 
'critical', 'details': '', 'expected': None, 'id': 10088898, 
'component_name': 'pudc-vm-001'}
```

By stanza i mean - in the above  `data` there are two stanzas. So how many ever there are, i need to get key and value pairs out of it and assign and create metrics as to those.